# chrome extension angular js scope not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am trying to create a simple chrome extension that uses angular but I am confused as to why the scope is not working.

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Test"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches" : [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js" : [
        "/js/lib/angular.min.js", "/js/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js", "/js/angularInit.js"
      ],
      "css" : [
        "/css/background.css"
      ],
      "all_frames" : true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

Here is where I am initing my module and controller

```
var curMod = angular.module('CurMod', []);
curMod.controller("curController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "JDF";
}]);
```

Here is my popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html ng-app="CurMod" ng-csp>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
      }
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 400px;
      }
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
     -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="curController">
      {{message}}
    </div>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <img id="image-result" hidden>
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems that the `{{message}}` is never populated even though I set it in angularInit.js in the curController.

Is there any other setup I need to do to get angular to work in chrome extension?

Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing `{{message}}` or nothing at all? What happens if you do `{{3 + 3}}`? Also, does your debugger show anything? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging

Comment: it says {{message}} and debugger is not showing any errors

Comment: Switch to the non minified version of angular and see if any errors pop up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have Angular in your popup!

Content scripts won't get injected in your own pages.

You need to add `<script>` tags to the `popup.html` itself.

Comment: @James You would probably be well served to go through the overview of extensions.  Content scripts, background scripts, and popup scripts are all different, and have different contexts in which they execute.

Comment: And Teepeemm helpfully omitted the link: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch